# Create PDF from ZF homepage with Report template

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, report

I have created a website for a customer that handles Productinformation and projectinformation about new and eventually new articles. In here are all the information needed for the article and also the Supplier adds their info.

And now to my problem, they ran this before in access and they had a report there to create an Declaration of Conformity. So its basically a report that prints an header with information from the DB and then you have an "body" area that is variable depending on how many European Standards or technical specs that are listed and then there is a footer with some text and then a picture/logo.

I am looking to replace this Access report to get all of the users to stop using the Access solution and get into the Web solution. So I am looking for a good reporting tool that is easy to use and preferably free. Anyone have good links or experiences with any tools?

Comment: Could you deliver some code or the Access report. I still don't understand what you need. Joomla an CMS or what?

Comment: I was thinking in the terms of Crystal reports or something. I have looked at JapserReports, maybe that is an option